# Can a homogenous electric/magnetic field vary in time?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, time

In either case I was thinking their curl is cero since they're homogenous. But that only leaves with
$- \frac{\partial B}{\partial t}=0$ for example, but then?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

In a parallel plate capacitor in an AC circuit, the electric field is constant and varies with time. As your equation verifies, there is no magnetic field

Comment: I disagree (but did not downvote). According to the [Ampere-Maxwell law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/maxeq2.html#c4)
an electric field $\mathbf{E}$ varying with time
is necessarily accompanied by a curling magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$.

Comment: How is it varying in time?

Comment: Yes, Ampere's law says the is aa time varying circular magnetic field, but I was answering the question, "Can a homogeneous magnetic field vary in time?"  I should have added the word 'homogeneous', but I thought it was understood because of the wording of the question